# How can I assign Keybindings for terminal in VS code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I want certain keyboard shortcuts work for me inside the PowerShell attached to **VS Code** because while typing commands I figure all the shortcut do not work in this PowerShell.

As an example I tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> to delete left word but it produces `^W`. How can I make modification to existing settings or configure new setting to get my job done? <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> is only an instance for the problem. There are many shortcuts I can configure with this.

Comment: actually, I'm surprised the default keybinding isn't working for you... is `ctrl+backspace` not bound to `workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence` for you by default? (check keyboard settings)

Comment: `{
  "key": "ctrl+backspace",
  "command": "deleteWordLeft",
  "when": "textInputFocus && !editorReadonly"
}`  This is all what I get. Can you guide me through this?

Comment: check default keybindings (using the `Preferences: Open Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` command in the command palette) and see if you have a `{ "key": "ctrl+backspace",  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence", "when": "terminalFocus", "args": {"text":"\u0017"} },`

Comment: It is the same I find. `{ "key": "ctrl+backspace",        "command": "deleteWordLeft",
                                     "when": "textInputFocus && !editorReadonly" }`

Comment: well, that's not what I told you to look for. Are you saying what I told you to look for isn't there?

Comment: yes, this is what you suggest me to look for.This is the default Keyborad Shortcut for `ctrl+backspace`

Comment: read what I asked you again and read it carefully.

Comment: Well, to be specific to your question. I can't see `{ "key": "ctrl+backspace",  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence", "when": "terminalFocus", "args": {"text":"\u0017"} },` at the place you told me to seek for

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you're looking for is the `terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell` setting. It's an array that you can fill with command strings that are IDs of commands that you want to be consume and interpreted by VS Code instead of being passed through to the shell.

Upon further investigation in the comments under the question, something seems wrong with your VS Code installation. Mine comes with the following in the default keybindings.json file (and you said yours does not), so I suggest you try manually adding to your user keybindings.json file:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+backspace",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "when": "terminalFocus",
    "args": { "text": "\u0017" }
},
```

Comment: yes of course. i am quite new to this. would you mind giving a demo?

Comment: I have already tried this but still not working. \